# Linux kernel startup problems: how to analyze?

Tags: drivers, kernel, opensuse

After manually updating the kernel from 2.6.33 to 2.6.34 on my OpenSuse 11.2 Notebook, it stops after the message

```
Loading drivers, configuring devices...
```

This stop can be interrupted with `Ctrl-C`, but when the system enters runlevel 5, no partitions are mounted (but the root partition), many services fail to start, and other strange things are going on. No X11.

*NOTE:*
*I manually updated the kernel many times before, it worked.*
*Yes, I know, in case of NVidia, the driver has to be recompiled.*

**The question is:**
**How can I analyze the cause of the problem?**

Doing `dmesg` gives me soooo much output, I can't "map" it to the output which I see at startup. The output does **not** contain the string `Loading drivers, configuring devices`, or similar.

Comment: The string that you are actually searching for in dmesg probably won't show up as it is echo'd from an init script. Can you post the output of dmesg to pastebin? Does networking work? Can you see interfaces with ifconfig? If so, you may be able to ssh into the box, dump it to a file, scp/sftp it over, and post it to a pastebin for us to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try booting with the `failsafe` options for the new kernel and see if that works correctly.

If it does, you can then edit the boot options to remove the options one by one to help identify what is causing the problem.

You could also try entering `single` at the boot options to enter single user mode. You can then log in as root and start poking around...